# Is there a method in the LinkedIn Rest API to see what companies a person is following?

Tags: rest, linkedin-api

Using the Linkedin Rest API, it's possible to pull a bunch of fields from their profile, but I can't find a method that would pull the companies that they're following. Does one exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the fields available for LinkedIn profiles can be retrieved using the **/v1/people** endpoint, depicted here: https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/documents/profile-api

But unfortunately there is no option to get the companies a user follows.